# How to get D3 csv data into a different variable

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to extract imdb data from a csv and put two elements of it into an array of objects.  There are 10 fields.  I only want to use 2 in my chart.  I am trying this:

```js
var mydata;

// Grab the data
d3.csv('./movies.csv', function(csv){
    csv.forEach(function(d){
        mydata += {rating: d.imdbRating,
                   winsNoms: d.WinsNoms };
    });
});

console.log(mydata);
```

Can somebody explain exactly what is going on here and why I get undefined when I try to output mydata in the final line?  Finally, how do I change it around so it works?

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need to first declare an empty array. Then you can push items into it.

To only use part of the set, you can use “slice” to truncate the array.

```
var mydata = [];

// Grab the data
d3.csv('./movies.csv', function(csv){
    csv.forEach(function(d){
        mydata.push({rating: d.imdbRating,
                   winsNoms: d.WinsNoms });
    });
});

console.log(mydata);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should push objects into an array. See adjustments below:

```js
var mydata = [];

// Grab the data
d3.csv('./movies.csv', function(csv){
    csv.forEach(function(d){
        mydata.push({
            rating: d.imdbRating,
            winsNoms: d.WinsNoms 
        });
    });
});

console.log(mydata);
```